# Turtlebot Autonomous Navigation

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, turtlebot, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I currently have completed all of the turtlebot tutorials. I have saved a map of some connecting hallways and can navigate trough them easily. I was wondering if there was a way to save a path for the turtlebot to follow autonomously instead of me giving it a goal every time.

So I should be able to go into rviz run this path and be able to watch the turtlebot go along this path without me interfereing. Just wondering on where to start, of if anyone has done this share what they have done.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27814/turtlebot-autonomous-navigation/) by [jwbary90](https://answers.ros.org/users/1142/jwbary90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-02-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could write a python script or a C++ program that sends goals to move_base (using [actionlib](http://ros.org/wiki/actionlib)).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3